# jQuery Scroll - Triggering a function ONCE when entering/exiting a scroll region

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I am working in JavaScript / jQuery (1.3.2) and have two functions:
open() and close()

The functions need to be called when based on a predefined point on the page which we wil call posY.

The open function needs to be triggered once the user scrolls below posY and the close function needs to be triggered once the person scrolls above posY again.

This is pretty easily done using the jQuery scroll feature.

My issue is that I only want the functions to be triggered ONCE - Open needs to be triggered ONE TIME on entering and Close needs to be triggered ONE TIME on exiting.

I have been trying for ages now, with different solutions that get more and more complicated than I thing it needs to be. Hopefully I'm being an idiot, missing a really simple solution.

For this project I cannot use any jQuery features above 1.3.2 and I want to avoid adding any external plugins if it can be avoided.

Thanks in advance!

edit:

I got asked to add some example code. This is the code I found on a different post on Stackoverflow, that I based my experiments on - I tried to stop it from triggering constantly by monitoring a variable, but it got a bit too complicated for me.
:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {

var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
var scroll_pos_test = 150;             // set to whatever you want it to be

if(y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test) {
    //do stuff
}
});
```

Comment: Could you post some code? What have you tried?

Comment: I added it in an edit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple!

```
.unbind();
```

Just unbind the event.
http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: This looks useful :D Thanks! Had no idea there was such a thing.

Comment: Unfourtantly i just made this account so I cant upvote :/ But you deffo got the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need this http://api.jquery.com/one/ . Need to see some code as well for a better explanation.